# Which word does "ever" modify in the sentence, "Have you ever seen that movie?"

Tags: adverbs

In the sentence,

> Have you ever seen that movie?

does the word "ever" modify "seen" or "have?" I know that it is an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

*Have seen* is a singular entity (main verb + its auxiliary), so *ever* is modifying them both simultaneously.

It's standard in English to place any auxiliaries in front of the subject and most adverbs when creating an interrogative sentence.

Comment: In modern grammar "(ever) seen that movie" is analysed as a subordinate catenative clause, so "ever" would be part of that clause only.

Comment: @BillJ you mean it's a past participle clause.And this clause together with the auxiliary verb form a Verb Phrase?

Comment: _Have ever seen that movie_ is a [verb phrase](http://www,umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), and so is _seen that movie_. _Ever_ is placed after the first auxiliary verb by rule, so it can be considered to modify either the VP it's in, or the VP it precedes. In any event, the more important point is that not every word has to modify some individual word in a sentence. Most modification is modification of phrases and clauses, not individual words, except in simple children's books. Adults use complex sentences most of the time.

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, it's a past-participial clause functioning as catenative complement of the auxiliary "have". The matrix clause "Have you ever seen that movie" has "have ever seen that movie" as VP. Within the matrix clause is the separate subordinate clause "ever seen that movie" as catenative complement of "have". The crucial point is that "have seen" is not "the verb": "have" is the matrix verb and "seen" is the subordinate verb.